# HTML Form Textarea carriage return causing Line breaks when read

Tags: php, html, ios, sql, database

I have a basic `textarea` inside a HTML Form like this:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
```

When text is inputted and submitted, it is sent to an SQL Database on an Amazon web server.

In my iOS App, I run a php file which returns a jSON Object which contains the content of this database.

When I print the content of this database in my App there are line breaks whenever a carriage return occurred in the `textarea`.

So the input box looks something like this:

[image]

Now, I **never** hit the `Enter` key once. These carriage returns happen automatically inside the input box.

And when I read the String in the app it looks something like this:

```
This is a multiline test to

check that everything is 

working fine.
```

How do I ignore these returns and store the text in the database as if it were one straight line of text.

I want it to look like this:

```
This is a multiline test to check that everything is working fine.
```

Do I need to do this at the iOS end? Or the HTML end? Or the PHP end?

Answer (score 0):

You could start by deleting all newline chars in the `textarea` with PHP's [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:

```
$description = preg_replace('/\n|\r/', ' ', $_POST['description']);
```

Place the code before storing into the database.

Comment: The problem here is, in some case I would like the user to input new lines by hitting `Enter`. I just want to remove the ones that the user didn't create. Which probably mean it has to be something in HTML which will solve this.

Comment: How do you display the HTML in your app? Do you output a paragraph `<p>` for every line stored in `description`?

Comment: I just pull the String (description) from the database and set the text equal to it

Comment: What type is your description field in the database? I'm afraid that I cannot reproduce the issue properly.

Comment: Pretty sure it is just `varchar`, should this matter?

Answer (score 0):

I notice you say you are using this code:

```
<textarea id="description" name="description"></textarea>
```

HTML 5 have introduced a [wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp) attribute.

The problem you have is that you have "Hard wrap" set, which is causing line breaks on wrapping.

Since "soft wrap" is set by default, I am assuming that somewhere you have "hard wrap" set.

Try inspecting the element and see what's going on here...

You should be able to just set `wrap="soft"` and force fix the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the replace as suggested to remove one of the two carriage return (`\r` or `\n` as you need)
For example:

```
preg_replace('/\n/', '',$description)
```

for the new line only